# Wordpress short code exclude by author

Tags: wordpress, author

I have a shortcode in WordPress which shows the last post by author, the problem is that I want to exclude a concrete author(ID=13). The shortcode is the next:

```
function latest_posts_c( $array ) {
    global $post;

    $defaults = array(
         'show' => 3,
         'excerpt' => 'false',
         'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    extract( shortcode_atts( $defaults, $array ) );

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $show,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
    );

    // Gets posts form database
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Displays posts if available
    if( $query ) {
        $i = 0;

        while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            if ($i == 0)
                $html = '<div class="column dt-sc-one-third first">';
            else
                $html .= '<div class="column dt-sc-one-third">';

            $html .= '<article id="post-'.get_the_ID().'" class="'.implode(' ', get_post_class('blog-entry')).'">';
            $html .= '<div class="blog-entry-inner">';

            $html .= '<div class="entry-meta">';
            $html .= '  <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" class="entry_format"> </a>';
            $html .= '  <div class="date">';
            $html .= '      <p>'.get_the_date('M').' '.get_the_date('d').' <span>'. get_the_date('Y') .'</span> </p>';
            $html .= '  </div>';
            $html .= '</div><!-- .entry-meta -->';

            if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                $html .= '<div class="entry-thumb">';
                $html .= '  <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'medium').'</a>';
                $html .= '</div><!-- .entry-thumb -->';
            endif;

            $html .= '<div class="entry-details">';
            if(is_sticky()):
            $html .= '  <div class="featured-post"> <span class="fa fa-trophy"> </span> Destacado</div>';
            endif;

            $html .= '  <div class="entry-title">';
            $html .= '      <h4><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>';
            $html .= '  </div>';

            $html .= '  <div class="entry-metadata">';
            $html .= '      <p class="author">';
            $html .=    '<span class="fa fa-user"> </span>';
            $html .= '          <a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')).'" title="Ver todos las entradas de '.get_the_author().'">'.get_the_author().'</a></p>'; 
            $categories = 0;/*get_the_category();*/
            $separator = ', ';
            $output = '';
            if($categories){
                $j = 0;
                foreach($categories as $category) {
                    $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "Ver todos las entradas en %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
                    $j++;
                    if ($j < count($categories)) $output .= $separator;
                }       
                $html .= '      <p class="categories"><span class="fa fa-folder-open"> </span>'.$output.'</p>';
            }
            $html .= '  </div><!-- .entry-metadata-->';

            $html .= '  <div class="entry-body">';
            $html .= '      '.dttheme_excerpt(50);
            $html .= '      <p><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" class="dt-sc-button small read-more">';
            $html .= '      Leer más <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"> </span></a></p>';
            $html .= '  </div>';

            $html .= '</div><!-- .entry-details -->';

            $html .= '</div><!-- .blog-entry-inner-->';
            $html .= '</article>';
        $html .= '</div>';

        $i++;
        endwhile;
    }

    $html .= '<div class="dt-sc-clear"></div>';

    // Resets Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Returns the results
   return $html;
}
add_shortcode('latestposts_c', 'latest_posts_c');
```

I added an If to block the code if there is a post from author ID=13, but the problem is that the shortcode doesn't show anything. I'm also using "authors_in" to allow certain authors ID inside the array $args and $default but nothing....Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $show,
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'author'   => '-13'
);
```

The author parameter can be set to include/exclude specific authors.

Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters